# Flutter doctor not detecting cmdlinetools and not letting me reinstall them

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, development-environment

I asked a question here a while back about how to fix the fact that I'm getting the "cmdline-tools component is missing" error when running flutter doctor even though I installed the "Android SDK Command-line tools" component in Android studio.

And no responses for how to fix it worked for me, So I attempted to re-install the commandline tools through the flutter console, seeing if that would fix the issue, and in order to do that, it says I need to run "(path to sdk manager) --install 'cmdline-tools;latest'" in the console, but when I attempt to do that, it gives me yet another error saying that the file location I typed "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" and refuses to install it.

I edited the environment variables to include the file path and restarted the flutter console, but that did nothing.

You can see the question I asked yesterday on my profile if that helps.

[Image of the error when I try installing the commandline tools through the flutter console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ligN2.png)

I also tried updating the cmdline tools with sdkmanager --update "cmdline-tools" and sdkmanager .bat --update "cmdline-tools" and I just got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1qy3.png), telling me sdkmanager isn't recognized as a command.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Paste text instead of images, please. It will be more readable

Comment: I typed what it said as a part of the question as well.